# get onclick events on drawable of textView using setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom)

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, android-drawable

I just wanted to know that can we get two different onclick event on `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom)` on textview.
first onclick on textview and other on drawable or can i get onclick on just drawable not the textview.?? Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: you can achieve this by wrapping this textView in a parent Layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieve it by listening to click event by myself. Like below:

```
    lTextView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && event.getX() < dpTopx(MainActivity.this, 19) )
            {
                Log.v("Click", "Clicked on back button");
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

where dpToPx is just a function converting dp to pixel. So now the left 19-dp region (containing a left drawable) is clickable.

Comment: what is that dptopx  function??

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. The compound object is ONE. Even if you decorate it with a drawable.
If you want two separate click events, then you have to use two different objects (i.e.: an ImageView and a TextView).
But it's NOT a best practice.

Comment: Actually i want the on-click only on draw-able not on  text-view,Is there any way to do so.

Comment: Then, you have to go for the **UNOPTIMIZED DESIGN** using 2 controls next to each one.

Answer (score 1):

event are getting only resource Id. so object have only one Id. so only one onClick event can be listen.
you can achieve this by wrapping this textView in a parent Layout

Comment: I will try to put a text-view and an image-view together in linear-layout so i can two different on-click events

Comment: yes then you can get one event of your textview and another one is for imageview and you can get one event for linearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Layout with image view and textview or edit view

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/black_border"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rdv_location_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_location_et"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="3"
        android:text="Address"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
```